# gdb with separate symbols file

Tags: gdb

I am trying to separate out debug symbols from my executable,

tried following:

https://www.zeuthen.desy.de/dv/documentation/unixguide/infohtml/gdb/Separate-Debug-Files.html

i.e.

```
 objcopy --only-keep-debug myelf myelf.debug
 strip -g myelf
```

With this debug file loaded (`symbol-file /path/to/myelf.debug` ) in `gdb`, when I get
a backtrace, I don't see the same number of frames. I also see an error!

There are `15` frames (though the details - file:line-number are not shown),
after loading the symbol file, I see `40`+ frames and an error message at the end

```
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

code is not compiled with `-fPIE`. Is there anything different at compile time or
with `objcopy` or `gdb` that I need, to get a proper backtrace with symbols?

I am on Ubuntu, the *binutils* version is `2.30`
and gdb `8.1.1`